# How to require Liskov-compliant overloads in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, overloading, liskov-substitution-principle

With [the following setup](https://tsplay.dev/WJRbZW):

```
class Base {
    doSomething(value: unknown): void {}
}

class Child extends Base {
    override doSomething(): void {}
}
```

… I expected a compiler error, related to the `value: unknown` parameter missing in `Child`'s overload of `doSomething` due to the violation of [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), but there is no such error (as seen in the playground).

Is there a way to enforce `Child.doSomething()` to *extend upon* `Base.doSomething()`, rather than overriding it completely?

Comment: There's no LSP violation. JavaScript doesn't really care about function/method arity, so you _can_ call `.doSomething(value)` on a `Child` instance via the `Base` interface. The fact that it doesn't _use_ that value isn't particularly relevant.

Comment: What _would_ be a violation is adding _more_ parameters, such that `.doSomething(value)` isn't a valid call: https://tsplay.dev/w2EJxW.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh, sure, you're right. Looks like I've confused the directions here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit simplified example:

```js
let base = (value: unknown) => { }

let child = () => { }

base = child

base(42) // ok
```

Assign of `child` to base is safe. Calling `base` with argument `base(42)` should not provide any unsafe behavior or error because it actually calls `child` which does not expect any argument.

From the other hand, assigning `child` to `base` is unsafe:

```js
let base = (value: unknown) => {
    console.log(value)
}

let child = () => { }

child = base // error

child()
```

TS forbids you to assign `base` to `child` because `base` expects some argument and calling `child` without argument might cause a runtime error.

More about function assignability you can find in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions)